# How do I perform SELECT * FROM depending on IF result in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function that declares some parameters and executing a select sentence that will populate a certain table. How can I add another select sentence and decide which one to execute based on an IF result that checks a certain parameter value from the declared parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: yes yes i got confused, i meant plsql apologies.

Comment: OK.  Are you executing a `select into`?  Or are you opening a cursor with the results of the `select` statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to perform a conditional check from the input parameter you declared, and then choose the SELECT to run. i.e.

```
DECLARE @parameter Integer = 10;
IF @Iteration < 20
  SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE;
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

This is just an example, replace the conditional part of the if with what you want your condition to be.

Comment: Do I need an "END IF" ?

Comment: Sorry i meant in PLSQL not TSQL

Comment: Yes, you need an "END IF;"